# Magento categories losing "include_in_menu" value - how?

Tags: mysql, attributes, magento, admin, categories

Magento CE 1.4 (also EE 1.8) introduced a new attribute to category entities; `include_in_menu`. I've checked very carefully and no code ever sets it to anything but "1". The default value is "1". There isn't an option to control it. And yet when some of my categories disappeared from the navigation I found this attribute had been cleared.

I can see `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Category/Tree.php` adds a filter for the attribute, this is how the value is being read. Sure enough, if I forcibly clear the value in the database those records are correctly filtered out and disappear from the front end navigation.

I've since reset all the values and it works fine now. However I don't understand why it went wrong nor how to prevent it happening again. Can anyone please suggest possible causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a user control in the admin under Manage Categories on the General Information tab called "Include in Navigation Menu".  Is it possible that this value was toggled manually?

Comment: Well I am surprised! I thought I had looked everywhere but I must not have scrolled far enough.

Comment: hehe, there's quite a few options to get lost amongst!! :) And it is a strange place for the field to be.  Up next to `isActive` would make more sense!

Comment: Yeah, we were so happy when they added this option instead of having to hack the nav code to not show them

Comment: @dan - ditto! Now if they could just add a feature to insert CMS pages into the nav, that would rock! :)

Comment: Yeah you got that right. I forgot about that, I have had several times where the client wanted us to link to a CMS page or a custom module in the dropdowns or nav

Comment: EE 1.8 has a rather nice hierarchical menu for CMS but it lacks any sort of scope control and still doesn't integrate with the catalog menu. Having two separate menu systems is just plain daft.